# How to delete data of multiple tables through Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have written the loop to delete the data in tables and print them

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Count INT = 1

WHILE @Count <> 0
BEGIN
      SET ROWCOUNT 100000

      DELETE
      FROM table1  

      SET ROWCOUNT 0

      SELECT @Count = COUNT(1)
      FROM table1  WITH (NOLOCK)

      --print '10000 Deleted'
      --Print cast (@count as varchar) + ' Remaining'
      DECLARE @Msg VARCHAR(100) = CAST(@Count AS VARCHAR) + ' Remaining'

      RAISERROR (
                  @Msg
                  , 0
                  , 1
                  )
      WITH NOWAIT
END
```

if i want to some 10 tables at one go

```
select * from Sysobjects where type = 'U' and name IN ('Table1,Table2',....)
```

how i need to implement the statement in the loop delete the data table data one by one .

Comment: Truncate table is faster and doesn't pack your transaction log.  Is there any reason that you want to delete within a loop instead of truncate?

Comment: @tgolisch Of course truncate table is better, minimal logging.  But like most posts, the user is being vague.  Drop table works fine also.  Just have to rebuild the schema?  ROFLOL

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (below).  It's not exactly what you're doing above, but you get the idea...

```
    SELECT id INTO #Processed FROM Sysobjects WHERE name = '(no such table)'

    DECLARE @TableId int, @TableName varchar(255), @DeletionSQL varchar(255)

    SELECT @TableId = MIN(id) FROM Sysobjects WHERE type = 'U' AND name IN ('DimAccount', 'DimCurrency', 'DimCustomer')
    AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM #Processed)

    SET @TableId = ISNULL(@TableId, -1)

    WHILE @TableId > -1 BEGIN

        PRINT @TableId

        SELECT @TableName = name FROM Sysobjects WHERE type = 'U' AND id = @TableId
        SET @DeletionSQL = 'DELETE FROM ' + @TableName

        PRINT @DeletionSQL
        EXEC(@DeletionSQL)


        INSERT INTO #Processed (id) VALUES(@TableId)

        SELECT @TableId = MIN(id) FROM Sysobjects WHERE type = 'U' AND name IN ('DimAccount', 'DimCurrency', 'DimCustomer')
            AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM #Processed)

    END
```

Answer (score -3):

Check out my blog article on deleting large data.  It gives a couple patterns to use.

http://craftydba.com/?p=3079

I suggest you pick one.  You could turn the code into dynamic SQL.

However, I would write a procedure for each table and package it up in a job.

One step, one table.

That way, you can restart the job at any step.

Watch out for log file growth!  Those details again are in the blog article.